# Can I print the rendered HTML of a JLabel?

Tags: java, html, swing

I'm writing a program that deals with basic graphics and lays them out in a specific format, and the idea is to have them print-ready. Since dealing with and modifying images directly is possible but kind of tedious, I thought of other ways to do this.

My first thought was to use something that uses XML, like SVG. And then it hit me: why not use HTML ([which Swing supports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) by default) to render the layout of the final product?

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><h1 style='color: blue;'>Hello world!</h1></html>");
```

The text of the component gets rendered as if it were content in a Web browser.

So, since of course we can print images using a `Graphics` object, is there a way we can capture the rendered HTML of the component as an image, and then print it?

[image: example]

Comment: "Printing" a component is a pretty basic/common concept (if you know about it ;)).  Basically, you create a `BufferedImage`, pass it's `Graphics` context to the `JLabel`'s `printAll` method and you have yourself an image of the component. You can the use `ImageIO.write` to save it, if you so wish.  Just make sure you size the `JLabel` properly before trying to print it ;)

Comment: Oh sweet, I didn't know about the `printAll` method. i wasn't sure what to look for, and it probably goes without saying that I haven't dealt with Java graphics printing that much. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's a little obscure ;)